# Eclipse XML Editor in custom FormEditor

Tags: xml, eclipse, xml-editor

I'm trying to develope an Editor for editing my own XML-Format. However I want to provide a "Source" tab, like some other editors (e.g. JPA Persistence XML editor).

My Editor class looks like this

```
public class DPUEditor extends FormEditor {

  public static final String ID = "de.lmu.ifi.dbs.knowing.ui.editor.DPUEditor"; //$NON-NLS-1$

  @Override
  protected void addPages() {
    try {
        addPage(new ConfigurationPage(this));
        //addPage(new XMLEditor(..)) <- add the XML Editor
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
...
}
```

I found out that org.eclipse.wst.xml provides the standard XML Editor for Eclipse. The short tutorial [here](http://www.java-forum.org/plattformprogrammierung/88910-xml-editor-project.html) didn't help me :(

I just want the plain IEditor where I can put in my IFileEditorInput.

thx,
Muki

Comment: The source XML Viewer isn't in located in org.eclipse.wst.xml.* as I thought. The class is called org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor. However it doesn't format my file if it doesn't end with .xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at Sapphire for a much easier way to build form+xml editors based on WTP XML Editor. With Sapphire, you define a semantic model for your data, specify how that model binds to XML using declarative annotations and then describe how to present the model in a form using declarative syntax. You end up with a better and more maintainable editor quicker since so much of the detail is taken care of by the framework.

[Intro to Sapphire](http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/documentation/latest/introduction/index.html)

[Sapphire Website](http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/)